# Hibernate generates error in your SQL syntax with MySQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, grammar

I am getting an error while try to fetch the record from table using HQL

> **Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.userinfo
>   userinfo0_ where userinfo0_.login_id='muskan' and
>   userinfo0_.pwd='musk' at line 1**
>
> **Full Error trace:**
>
> from Userinfo userinfo where userinfo.loginId='muskan' and
>   userinfo.pwd='muskan@admin' and userinfo.role='Administrator'Exception
>   in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could
>   not execute query     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2452)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)   at
>   org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)     at
>   com.ovs.domain.UserDAO.validateUser(UserDAO.java:16)  at
>   com.ovs.action.LoginTest.main(LoginTest.java:17) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.userinfo
>   userinfo0_ where userinfo0_.login_id='muskan' and
>   userinfo0_.pwd='musk' at line 1   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2643)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2228)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1869)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)     ... 9 more

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `userinfo` (
  `login_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `lastlogon` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`login_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Hibernate Settings:**

```
<name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
```

**Java code:**

```
String query="from Userinfo userinfo where userinfo.loginId='"+userinfo.getLoginId()+"' and userinfo.pwd='"+ userinfo.getPwd()+
                      "' and userinfo.role='"+userinfo.getRole()+"'";   
        Query validateUserQuery= getsession().createQuery(query);

        System.out.print(validateUserQuery.getQueryString());
        List<Userinfo> result = validateUserQuery.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try  to change in your query userinfo.loginId by userinfo.login_id

Comment: Thanks I tried changing userinfo.loginid by userinfo.login_id but with no results. Still getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can show "Userinfo" entity class or XML.
In query you can use parameters so your string will look better and to protect yourself from SQL injections.

```
String query="from Userinfo u where u.loginId = :loginId"
Query validateUserQuery= getsession().createQuery(query);
validateUserQuery.setParameter("loginId",userinfo.getLoginId());
```